# Wubildr.mbr is missing or corrupted

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, wubi

I just installed Ubuntu using WUBI. I followed this [tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b6Ycx2K2OeY&feature=related) and when I select Ubuntu from Windows boot loader, it says `wubildr.mbr is missing or corrupted`.

Then Windows boot manager appears again. I try again. The same error. Then I go to Windows, and checked the `wubildr.mbr` which is in `winboot`. It is only 8 kb big. Is  that normal? Is it corrupted? And one more thing. When I  installed using WUBI, I got that error screenshot on (http://94.140.81.66/error.png)

Answer (score 2):

Wubi does not support UEFI BIOS, look [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/694242), making it useless for any modern laptop.